# Complex $\Gamma$-function is holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

> How can I show that $\Gamma$ function is holomorphic ?

I have to show it by dominated convergence theorem or by Morera's Theorem

For $\Re(z)>0$ the $\Gamma$-function is defined as
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle\Gamma(z)=\int_0^{\infty}x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx~\text{and let}~f:G\times I\to \mathbb C~\text{with}~f(z,x)=x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx
\end{equation*}

then there is a compact set $K\subset G$ and an integrable function $\phi:I\to\mathbb R$ such that $|f(z,x)|\le\phi(x)$ for $z\in K, x\in I$, then $\Gamma$ is holomorphic. How can I choose $\phi$ ?

Or what is the condition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem#Infinite_sums_and_integrals) for a closed path to be ''suitable'' ?

Does somebody know why I cannot get [the derivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20e%5E%28-x%29%20x%5E%28z-1%29%20log%28x%29%20with%20respect%20to%20x%20from%200%20to%20infty) ?

Comment: So you mean the Gamma function *only* as defined by that integral, without its analytic continuation?

Comment: @Timbuc with the constraint that $\Re(z)>0$

Comment: @Ob Yesw, of course...otherwise the integral doesn't converge.

Comment: "there is **a** compact set $\;K\;$ ..."? For analicity as you want this must be true for *all* compact subsets  in the given domain.

Answer (score 3):

Any compact set $K\subset\mathbb{C}$ is included in a bounded vertical strip :$\forall z\in K, \{0<a\leq\Re(z)\leq b<+\infty\}$.

$|x^{z-1}|\leq x^{\Re(z)-1}|\leq x^{\Re(b)-1}|$ $(x>0)$ implies $|\Gamma(z)|\leq \Gamma(\Re(z)) \leq \Gamma(b)$ $(z\in K)$

Convergence of the integral is then normal, uniform convergence follows and Weierstrass convergence theorem for holomorphic function applies.

Answer (score 0):

$f(z,x)$ is a continuous function of $(z,x)\in (\text{Re}(z)>0,(0,\infty))$, the continuity of $f(z,x)$ in $z$ variable is uniform with respect to closed and bounded intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. For fixed $x_{0}>0$, $f(z,x_{0})$ is a holomorphic function of $z$. Its derivative $f_{z}(z,x)$ is a continuous function of $x$. The limit $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{0}^{R}f(z,x)\mathrm{d}x$ exists uniformly in $z$, i.e. for every compact set $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ contained in $\Omega$ and for every $\epsilon>0$, we can find $R$ such that
\begin{equation}
\left|\int_{R}^{\infty}f(z,x)\mathrm{d}x\right|<\epsilon\ \text{for every}\ z\in D
\end{equation}

Let $\mathbb{H}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\text{Re}(z)>0\}$, consider the following two integrals:
\begin{equation}
\left|\int_{0}^{s}x^{z-1}e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x\right|\ \text{and}\ \left|\int_{S}^{\infty}x^{z-1}e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x\right|
\end{equation}
It only needs to show these two values are less than every $\epsilon>0$ when $z$ is in any compact subset $D\subset\mathbb{H}$. Choose $A,B>0$ such that for every $z\in D,A<\text{Re}(z)<B$, this can be done since $D$ is a closed and bounded set in $\mathbb{H}$.

Since $A>0$, $x^{A}=e^{A\ln(x)}\to 0$ as $x\to 0+$. Choose $0<r<1$ small enough so that $r^{A}<A\epsilon$. For $0<x<1$, $|x^{z-1}|=e^{\text{Re}(z-1)\ln(x)}\leq e^{(A-1)\ln(x)}=x^{A-1}$. For any $0<s<r$, we have
\begin{equation}
\left|\int_{0}^{s}x^{z-1}e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x\right|\leq\left|\int_{0}^{s}x^{A-1}\mathrm{d}x\right|=\frac{s^{A}}{A}<\frac{r^{A}}{A}<\epsilon
\end{equation}
For $x>1$, $|x^{z-1}|=x^{\text{Re}(z-1)}\leq t^{B-1}$. Using the fact $x^{B-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$, we can choose $x_{0}>0$ such that $x^{B-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\leq 1$ for every $x\geq x_{0}$. Pick $R>1$ and larger than $x_{0}$, $e^{-\frac{R}{2}}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then for any $S>R$ we have

\begin{equation}
\left|\int_{S}^{\infty}x^{z-1}e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x\right| \leq \int_{S}^{\infty}(x^{B-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}})e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\mathrm{d}x\leq\int_{S}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\mathrm{d}x=2e^{-\frac{S}{2}}<2e^{-\frac{R}{2}}<\epsilon
\end{equation}

After showing this, according to the theorem stated above, $\Gamma(z)$ is a holomorphic function in $\text{Re}(z)>0$.